# Display content in place of post-content with plugin on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to display specific content like string "testing" not in header or footer but there where the text of the posts should be seen with my own plugin.

```
add_action('wp', 'test');
function test() {
echo " 'test' instead of post text";
};
```

Comment: use filter 'the_content'

Comment: Thx its an answear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', function( $content ) {
      return 'Hello World '.$content; }, 0);
```

You can use the_content with an high prioriety (lower number).

Comment: Actually 0 is the wrong direction. You want the filter to be applied last so it cannot be overridden.